# value of array changes for no reason JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

The contents of arr[] change somehow so when I try to print the contents of the returned array from the method it says null.
This method takes a text file path from the user and puts every individual word into an array and compares it with a dictionary array (book) and the ones that aren't in the dictionary are supposed to be returned in dif[].

```
  int d = arr.length-compare(book, arr);
  int l = 0;
  int bi = 0;
  String[] dif = new String[d];
  if (d >= 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      for (int a = 0; a < book.length; a++) {
        if (book[a].equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i])) {
//IF I TRY TO PRINT ARR[I] HERE IT HAS A VALUE
          bi = 1;
        }
      }
      if (bi != 1) {
        dif[l] = arr[i];
//HERE ARR[I] IS NULL
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
        l = l + 1;
      }
    }
    return dif;
  }
  else {
    return null;}
}
```

Comment: Two things:  1)  I beg you, use actual variable names that are descriptive.  It's hard to navigate what you mean by "d" and "arr" and "dif".  2) You're explicitly assigning a value to `arr`.  Are you sure `dif` isn't empty?  Kinda looks like it is to me.

Comment: You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @JoeC:  This is actually the right amount of code to identify the problem.  It's fairly obvious given how the OP has commented around it.

Comment: I can't see the cause, and I can't debug it because the OP has not provided everything that's needed to do so.  Thus, it is not an MCVE.

Comment: IMO there is no way that `arr[i]` is changing in the **posted** code... there must be something missing, or the `null` is already in `arr`

Comment: @Makoto sorry this was just supposed to be a simple method. Yes dif is initialized empty as a size determined by a formula, not important.  The problem is that when I try to put the certain contents of arr[] into dif[], arr[] is all of a sudden empty. Sorry for any confusion but where I commented is what i am having trouble with.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I understand why you would think that. but when I try to print the contents of arr[] after running the loops it prints nothing.

Comment: thanks for any help guys i will be back in a couple hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (int a = 0; a < book.length; a++) {
    if (book[a].equalsIgnoreCase(arr[i])) {
//IF I TRY TO PRINT ARR[I] HERE IT HAS A VALUE
      bi = 1;
    }
  }
  if (bi != 1) {
    dif[l] = arr[i];
//HERE ARR[I] IS NULL
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
    l = l + 1;
  }
}
```

You never reset the value of `bi`, so as soon as there is one entry in `arr` that is equal to one entry in `book` all subsequent values in `arr` will be outputted which might include `null`.

Comment: I don't deserve an account on this website